# How do i implement a cup object as a list of dice objects in python?

Tags: python, class, oop

I've implemented a Dice class in python with it's position attribute and roll method, but I've been trying to implement a cup of 5 dices that initializes an n number of dices using lists, Here's my code :

```
import random

class Dice:
    def __init__(self, pos=1):
        self.pos = pos
        

def get_position(self):
    return self.pos

def set_position(self,pos):
    self.pos=pos

def roll(self):
    self.pos=random.randint(1,6)
    return self
def __str__(self):
    return self.pos

class cup:
    def __init__(self, num):
       self=[Dice() for k in range(num)]

    def cup_roll(self):
       for k in self:
            k.roll()
       return self
    def __str__(self):
       return str([k.get_position() for k in self])

##----------Test---------------##

from dice import Dice
from dice import Cup
LD=Cup(5)
print(LD)
```

I now want to implement a cup object using lists for 5 dices objects, this list will have each dice object represented by it's position i.e 5 dice that rolled 1,2,3,4,5 will be represented by the list [1,2,3,4,5] however i still want to roll the cup effectively rolling the 5 dices at once, the tests return typeError not iterable, Thank you for any recommendations  :) !

Answer (score 0):

You need to bind the 5 dice to a variable in the `Cup` class:

```
self.dice = [Dice() for k in range(num)]
```

The `self` in here means the instance of the class itself so you can't rebind that. Class variables are defined with `self.<var>` dot notation. Then in `cup_roll` and `__str__` you can use that variable with

```
def cup_roll(self):
   for k in self.dice:
        k.roll()
   return self.dice

def __str__(self):
   return str([k.get_position() for k in self.dice])
```

Then in your test you want to roll the cup before printing it out:

```
LD=Cup(5)
LD.cup_roll()
print(LD)
```

Also, if the class definitions are in the same file, you don't need to import them at all.